# Minor child’s passport and blue card expired in Germany

Tags: germany, immigration, resident-permit, children, passports

Currently I am living in Germany and  my daughter’s passport and blue card both are expired on Jan 31, 2024, but i just noticed it today.

I am completely blank, could anyone please guide, how does it go with kids (10 years old).

Looking forward to hearing your views on it.

Comment: Thank for your post I am also facing the similar issue. Can I reach you to get some more doubts Is it the temporary visa will be sent immediately so that I can apply for the passport extension and can you also share how much time did it took for the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

A child of 10 has a blue card? Or has the residence permit of the **dependent** child simply expired with the passport?

Since the childs residence permit is **derived** from the parents residence permit, getting a new passport and then going to the Immigration Office with the parent with the Blue Card to get the residence permit renewed would be the simplest solution.

Only when the child become 18, will a residence permit be issued for them based on their own rights, taking into account the duration of the previous periods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response!

If anyone facing the similar issue, they must contact their city registration department dealing with Foreign affairs. The Department simply ask for the basis details of the minor / applicant so keep it handy while contacting them over the phone.post checking their records, they post the temporary visa to the residential address of the applicant.

After receiving that one can visit ICG for passport reissuance, please note that temporary visa is mandatory for passport renewal/ re-issuance.

Hope this information helps someone.